# Getting Connection timed out while I run composer global require laravel/installer on Ubuntu

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, composer-php

I am getting "[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]" error when I run `composer global require`.

[image: console screenshot; console error message]

But composer is installed successfully.

[image: console screenshot; installed composer version]

I am using `php version 7.3.10` , `composer 1.9.0` and `Ubuntu 18.04`

Comment: Is this in a corporate network? Are there any firewalls that may interfere? Does composer work for other packages?

Comment: I am using local broadband internet connection, and composer is not working for any other packages too. @MaartenDev

Comment: Are you sure the server is connected to the internet? does curl work?

Comment: It was IPv6 issue, I have fixed my IPv6 setup now everything is alright.

The solution link:

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#operation-timed-out-ipv6-issues-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was IPv6 issue, I have fixed my IPv6 setup now everything is alright.

Step1:

`sudo sh -c "echo 'precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100' >> /etc/gai.conf"`

After this command composer will work properly.

[Operation timed out (IPv6 issues)](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#operation-timed-out-ipv6-issues-)